# Properly hovering over isometric tile sprite

Tags: actionscript-3, events, isometric

I have four classes: Room, TileGrid, HoverTile, and Tile.

Room is composed of walls and a TileGrid. TileGrid is made out of Tile. Currently, I use this code to generate a TileGrid out of Tiles:

```
    this.mapArray = [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                         [1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                         [1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                         [1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                         [1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                         [1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                         [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]];

        this._mapHeight = this.mapArray.length;
        this._mapWidth = this.mapArray[0].length;
        this._tileHeight = 23;
        this._tileWidth = 46;

        var initialX:Number = 260;
        var initialY:Number = 150;

        for (var isoY:int = 0; isoY < mapArray.length; isoY++)
        {
            for (var isoX:int = 0; isoX < mapArray[isoY].length; isoX++)
            {
                if (isoX == 0 && isoY == 0)
                {
                    var _tile:Tile = new Tile();
                    _tile.x = initialX;
                    _tile.y = initialY;
                    this.addChild(_tile);
                }

                if (this.mapArray[isoY][isoX] == 1)
                {
                    var _tile:Tile = new Tile();
                    _tile.x = initialX - (isoX * 20) - (isoY * 20);
                    _tile.y = initialY - (isoX * 10) + (isoY * 10);
                    addChild(_tile);

                    _tile.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, updateHover);
                }
            }
        }
```

My current issue is that I want to add a white square around the tile that a mouse is hovering over. The code I used to use wasn't sufficient, because transparent parts of the Tile sprite are still counted as part of it. So even if I'm pointing at another Tile2 (which is next to Tile1), for example, if I'm not far enough onto Tile2, it'll highlight Tile1.

So, here's the current code I'm using:

```
    public function updateHover(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var mX:int = e.stageX - (_tileWidth / 2);
        var tPoint:Point = pointToXY(mX, e.stageY);

        var isoX = tPoint.x;
        var isoY = tPoint.y;

        if (isoX >= 0 && isoY >= 0)
        {
            if (isoY < mapArray.length)
            {
                if (isoX < mapArray[0].length)
                {
                    tPoint = xyToPoint(isoX, isoY);
                    _tileHover.x = tPoint.x;
                    _tileHover.y = tPoint.y;
                    _tileHover.visible = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        _tileHover.visible = false;
    }

    public function pointToXY(x:int, y:int):Point
    {
        x -= 260;
        y -= 150;

        var pRatio:int = (_tileWidth / 2) / (_tileHeight / 2);
        var tX:int = (y + x / pRatio) * (pRatio / 2) / (_tileWidth / 2);
        var tY:int = (y - x / pRatio) * (pRatio / 2) / (_tileWidth / 2);

        return new Point(tX, tY);
    }

    public function xyToPoint(x:int, y:int):Point
    {
        x -= 1;

        var worldPoint:Point = new Point(0, 0);
        worldPoint.x = (x * (_tileWidth / 2)) - (y * (_tileWidth / 2));
        worldPoint.y = (x * (_tileHeight / 2)) + (y * (_tileHeight / 2));
        worldPoint.x = worldPoint.x + (_tileWidth / 2);
        worldPoint.y = worldPoint.y + (_tileHeight / 2);
        worldPoint.x += 260;
        worldPoint.y += 150;

        return worldPoint;
    }
```

Sorry I have to post so many code blocks. Now, 260 and 150 are the default starting point for the entire room. That said, I'm really confused on how to get the last two functions in particular to work so that they'll give me the correct answer. This is what I expected from using this code:

[image]

That would be perfect. But, again, I don't know why the code isn't working. The sizes are all correct and I believe the offset is, too. So, I'm

Comment: What does your current, undesired behaviour look like?

Comment: You are creating two `Tile` objects for (0,0) coordinates. And, you should probably use `e.localX` and `e.localY` as coordinates passed to `pointToXY()`. Also consider running a debug textfield that'll show you current coordinates, the result of `pointToXY()` and the backwards transformation, it's quite possible that there's a typo in either of the xy<->point functions.

Comment: also, there are libraries that do a lot of this for you, [like as3isolib](https://github.com/as3isolib/as3isolib.v1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should add the listener to `this`, not to `_tile`, because then you are locked to stage coordinates to determine the tile that's selected, which is not good. Second, your listener should be against `MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE` event, not over, this way you'll constantly get updated mouse coords to properly move your rectangle over tiles. And you have a minor error out there, you have a (0,0) tile created two times, one being inactive.

```
    for (var isoY:int = 0; isoY < mapArray.length; isoY++)
    {
        for (var isoX:int = 0; isoX < mapArray[isoY].length; isoX++)
        {
            if (this.mapArray[isoY][isoX] == 1)
            {
                var _tile:Tile = new Tile();
                _tile.x = initialX - (isoX * 20) - (isoY * 20);
                _tile.y = initialY - (isoX * 10) + (isoY * 10);
                addChild(_tile);
            }
        }
    }
    this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, updateHover);
```

Also, it'll be better that you'd store (x,y) pairs on the array (as tiles, most likely), so that your initial array of zeroes and ones would transform into an array of `Tile` objects. To do that, you first do this:

```
this.tileArray=[];
for (var i:int=0;i<this.mapArray.length;i++) 
   this.tileArray.push(new Array(this.mapArray[i].length));
```

This will create an array of nulls that matches your `mapArray` by dimensions, that will serve as placeholder for created `Tile` objects. After you do this, you call `this.tileArray[isoY][isoX]=_tile;` to place the newly created tile to its place. After that, you can rewrite your listener to this:

```
public function updateHover(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var p:Point=pointToXY(e.localX,e.localY);
    _tileHover.visible = false; // hide hover for now
    if ((p.y<0) || (p.y>=tileArray.length)) return;  // range error on Y
    if ((p.x<0)||(p.x>=tileArray[p.y].length)) return; // range error on X
    if (!tileArray[p.y][p.x]) return; // no tile
    var _tile:Tile=tileArray[p.y][p.x];
    _tileHover.x=_tile.x;
    _tileHover.y=_tile.y; // no need to convert xyToPoint() we have coords stored in tile
    _tileHover.visible=true;
}
```

Comment: For some reason, there's always a range error! I'm beginning to think the `ptToXY()` and `xyToPt()` functions are just wrong.

Comment: It's possible. You might decide to have a textfield on your display list (a child of `TileGrid`, most likely) that will display mouse coords and whatever returns as `pointToXY()`. And, since that thing throws range errors instead of receiving null, the checks should be patched to `if ((p.y<0) || (p.y>=tileArray.length)) return; if ((p.x<0)||(p.x>=tileArray[p.y].length)) return; if (!tileArray[p.y][p.x]) return;`

Comment: ALso, look, your tiles are spaced by 20 and 10 when you place them (my code is copy&paste from yours, I didn't change the constants in any way), but you use 26 and 13 in `pointToXY()`! Check if this is an unintentional error and fix.

Comment: It looks like it IS the formula..so I don't know what to do about that. Either way, I'm going to select your answer as the solution because it's so wise.